# How is black hole affected by gravity of nearby bodies?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

I run into wikipedia articles about ergosphere of rotating black holes. What if some massive body passes nearby some black hole: is something like ergosphere produced, or is the event horizon distorted by the gravity of the passing body?

Comment: To be honest I don't know, however it strikes me that merging of two black holes would be a good place to start. Googling will find no end of articles and animations on the subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both will exert force on each other. If the body passing nearby it is more massive then it will attract black hole with greater force of gravity than the block hole.

Comment: This doesn't address the essential question at all.